# Cannot access empty property in /var/www/clients/client1/web9/web/modules/field/field.attach.inc

Tags: 7, views

I was deleting nodes using [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and suddenly I got a white screen.

In my error log I get the following error:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in /var/www/clients/client1/web9/web/modules/field/field.attach.inc on line 324

I'm using domain module and my other subdomains work fine, but my main domain always gives me a white screen with that error.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem: https://drupal.org/node/2051839

Apparently there's something wrong with my image field of a slider, I have no idea that happened during bulk delete of a different content type.